Not all the elements inside of the <div> are rendered. React.js
Recipe Card with button labelled "View Recipe"
This is a recipe application where all of the data displayed is fetched from spoonacular (API) and when the user clicks on the button (View Recipe) on a recipe card details about the recipe are displayed, as shown below.
Only the h2 element with text: Ingredients is rendered but the other div is not
All the details are shown except for the Ingredients and no error messages are displayed.
Code of parent component of IngredientsList (the parent of all components is App.jsx):
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import styles from "./FoodDetails.module.css";
import IngredientsList from "./IngredientsList";

export default function FoodDetails({ foodId }) {
  const [recipe, setRecipe] = useState({});
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const URL = `https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/${foodId}/information`;
  const API_KEY = "";
  let UniqueKey = 0;

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchRecipe() {
      const res = await fetch(`${URL}?apiKey=${API_KEY}`);
      const data = await res.json();
      console.log(data);
      setRecipe(data);
      setIsLoading(false);
    }

    if (foodId !== "") {
      fetchRecipe();
    }
  }, [foodId]);

  if (foodId !== "") {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className={styles.recipeContainer}>
          <h1 className={styles.recipeName}>{recipe.title}</h1>
          <img className={styles.recipeImage} src={recipe.image} alt="" />
          <div className={styles.recipeDetails}>
            <span>
              ⏳<strong>{recipe.readyInMinutes} Minutes</strong>
            </span>
            <span>
              ‍‍‍ <strong>Serves {recipe.servings}</strong>
            </span>
            <span>
              <strong>
                {recipe.vegetarian ? " vegetarian" : " non-vegetarian"}
              </strong>
            </span>
            <span>
              <strong>{recipe.vegan ? " vegan" : ""}</strong>
            </span>
            <span>
              <strong>
                ${Math.floor(recipe.pricePerServing / 100)} Per Serving
              </strong>
            </span>
          </div>

          <div>
            <h2>Ingredients</h2>
            <IngredientsList recipe={recipe} isLoading={isLoading} />
          </div>
          
          <div className={styles.recipeInstructions}>
            <h2>Instructions</h2>
            <ol>
              {isLoading ? (
                <p>Loading....</p>
              ) : (
                recipe.analyzedInstructions[0].steps.map((step) => (
                  <li key={(UniqueKey = UniqueKey + 1)}>{step.step}</li>
                ))
              )}
            </ol>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Part of the code causing the problem:
<div>
     <h2>Ingredients</h2>
     <IngredientsList recipe={recipe} isLoading={isLoading} />
</div>

<IngredientsList /> is the child component, containing ingredient component, which accepts recipe and isLoading as props.
Code inside <IngredientsList />:
import Ingredient from "./Ingredient";

export default function IngredientsList({ recipe, isLoading }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {isLoading ? (
        <p>Loading....</p>
      ) : (
        recipe.extendedIngredients.map((item) => {
          <Ingredient item={item} />;
        })
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

extendedIngredients is an array property of the object containing all the data and recipe is the object so using map i looped through it and got each "detail" object as item and passed it to <Ingredient /> component as a prop.
Code inside <Ingredient />:
export default function Ingredient({ item }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <img
        src={`https://img.spoonacular.com/ingredients_100x100/` + item.image}
        alt=""
      />

      <div>
        <h1>{item.name}</h1>
        <p>
          {item.amount} {item.unit}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

All of the contents of the  in Ingredient is not displayed.
I thought that the extendedIngredients array property could not be accessed as an error message was there at first but when using console.log() on the item prop it displayed the object with no errors. However, when writing deleting all of the contents of the div in Ingredient.jsx and creating and h1 element instead, it is rendered.

In your code, the map function is not returning the Ingredient component. It should be returning the JSX element for each item. Additionaly each component should be unique so key must be added and if you dont have unique key you can always replace it wih index passed in map function.
import Ingredient from "./Ingredient";

export default function IngredientsList({ recipe, isLoading }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {isLoading ? (
        <p>Loading....</p>
      ) : (
        recipe.extendedIngredients.map((item) => (
          <Ingredient key={item.id} item={item} />
        ))
      )}
    </div>
  );
}


what was the problem exactly because the difference between my code and yours is instead of wrapping the Ingredient component in curly braces you wrapped them in parenthesis so could you please clarify?

Using parentheses () instead of {} allows you to return the JSX directly without an explicit return statement or in case of {} in your previous code, you have to return the the ingredient.
